# «От того» или «оттого»? Давайте разберемся!

Tags: орфография, предлоги, слитно-раздельно, наречия

**Друзья, несмотря на дискуссионность вопроса, буду крайне благодарна за оперативность!**

Проблем не видела, пока моя мама (*ас в русском языке!*) не отметила меня, мягко говоря, неправой.
Я сомневаюсь, но хочу приобрести уверенность. Просьба: приведите свой доводы для закрепления темы. Ниже привожу свою логику по правилу.
Еще ниже, собственно, те самые спорные предложения.

**Правило:**
 а) «от того» — предлог, заменяется на «от того самого (этого)».
Пример: *Оттолкнуться **от того** камня!*

б) «оттого» — наречие причины, заменяется на «потому», «потому что», «поэтому».
Пример:  *Оттолкнуться **оттого**, что нам это необходимо для выживания!*

***Нашла еще один спорный вопрос***:
«оттого что» в значении «потому что» **не разделяется запятой**?
При этом не указывается: **от чего** подобное зависит!
(Эта информация найдена в просторах интернета, в том числе здесь: это "правило" не из справочников.)
Какие у вас мысли на этот счет?

**Примеры:**

1. Ни страха от того, что будет, ни сожалений о том, что случилось, ни даже любви!
2. Ведь невозможно не ощутить всю гамму эмоций оттого, как движущаяся бездна пожирает планеты.
3. Меня заполняет немыслимый страх оттого, что все окажется сном.
4. Меня грызет совесть оттого, что затронула эту тему.
5. Выдохнул, возможно, оттого, что подобрал не те слова.
6. Я обернусь, но не оттого, что так будет правильно, а оттого, что в его голосе появилось участие.
7. Не знаю, оттого ли, что сумел уловить мое возмущение, но, спасибо.
8. Не сдерживаю вопроса оттого, что уже не наблюдаю его даже на экране.
9. Улыбается он. Оттого, что он вспомнил? Или оттого, что видит на моем лице странную реакцию.
10. К своей плоти и крови она могла обратиться только по имени не оттого, что не любила, а просто понимала - не имеет на иное прав.
11. Но он не растерялся и прямиком направился к дому, где с удивлением оттого, что он один, его встретила девушка.
12. Ее охватывал ужас оттого, что никогда не сможет увидеть семью.
13. Она все же помотала отрицательно головой, но не оттого, что ей неприятны прикосновения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исправлены ошибки:

2.Ведь невозможно не ощутить всю гамму эмоций (от чего?) **от того**, как движущаяся бездна пожирает планеты.

11.Но он не растерялся и прямиком направился к дому, где с удивлением (от чего?) **от того**, что он один, его встретила девушка.

Имеется в виду, что девушка удивилась тому, что он один.

+++++
Впрочем, можно придать этому предложению другой смысл. Девушка встретила его с удивлением (почему?), оттого что он один. В этом случае "оттого что он один" должно быть выделено запятыми, тире или скобками как пояснение;

Но он не растерялся и прямиком направился к дому, где с удивлением — оттого что он один — его встретила девушка.

(Добавлено под влиянием замечаний @Мимоходов)
++++

12.Ее охватывал ужас (от чего?) **от того**, что никогда не сможет увидеть семью.

Аналогичный пример:

*Измайлов пришел в ужас от того, что Васенька в стихах изъяснялся валдайским мужицким говором[В. Ф. Ходасевич. Жизнь Василия Травникова (1936)]*

Этот вариант кажется мне более предпочтительным, но возможно и другое прочтение:

Ее охватывал ужас (почему?) **оттого**, что никогда не сможет увидеть семью.

Аналогичный пример:

*Погасший свет вызывал в нем злобу и легкий ужас оттого, что его могут попросить подойти к пробкам и починить их. [Галина Щербакова. Реалисты и жлобы (1997)]*

Comment: С категоричностью № 11 не согласен. Здесь я вижу скорее "не от чего", а именно "почему".

Comment: @Мимоходов. Удивляются обычно чему-то, а не отчего-то. Девушка, скорее всего, удивлялась тому, что он один, а не потому что он один.

Comment: К тому же там не глагол "удивляться", а существительное "удивление". Вопрос "почему?" нужно отнести к глаголу. Не думаете же вы, что она его встретила потому, что он один.

Comment: Удивиться чему-то -> Удивление от чего-то -> Удивление от того, что...

Comment: благодарю за разъяснение, для меня оно очень полезно! Только вот вывод-то какой? Следуя Вашим примерам,  получается в некоторых случаях идет выбор на УСМОТРЕНИЕ АВТОРА между «оттого» (потому что), когда мы ВЫБИРАЕМ и отталкиваемся от конкретного (изъяснительного) слова, от которого задаем вопрос, и «от того» (от чего). Вижу, мне дан ответ, что чаще отталкиваются от существительного, но конкретно правила такого не вижу. И как быть?

Comment: Не думаю, что процесс принятия решения можно как-то формализовать. Вы должны понять тонкую разницу в оттенках смысла,  например, человек ужасался чему-что (ее охватывал ужас от того, что...) или ужасался по какой-то причине (ее охватывал ужас оттого, что...)

Answer (score 3):

1) **Надо отличать предложения с местоименной связью** (от того, что) **от предложений с союзной связью** (оттого, что; потому, что).  **В первом случае** ЧТО  – союзное слово, ОТ ТОГО – указательное слово : Ни страха от того (от чего?), что будет, ни сожалений о том (о чем?), что случилось, ни даже любви!
**Во втором случае** ЧТО входит в состав союза. Союзы причины  ОТТОГО ЧТО и  ПОТОМУ ЧТО являются синонимами, этот факт используется при проверке.

Кроме того, указательные слова могут встречаться **в изъяснительных предложениях:** Ее охватывал ужас от того, что никогда не сможет увидеть семью. Здесь ЧТО – союз.

Чаще указательное слово относится к существительным, чем к глаголам. Она ужаснулась, оттого что (потому что) не надеялась с ним больше увидеться. Её охватил ужас от того,  что она не надеялась с ним больше увидеться. Такие предложения могут иметь **авторское решение.**

Отметим, что если  ОТТОГО ЧТО и  ПОТОМУ ЧТО **не взаимозаменяемы**, то значение причины отсутствует, и тогда ОТ ТОГО однозначно является указательным словом:
Но он не растерялся и прямиком направился к дому, где с удивлением **от того,** что он один, его встретила девушка.

2) Нужно исправить предложение 2: **Ведь невозможно не ощутить всю гамму эмоций оттого, как движущаяся бездна пожирает планеты.** Здесь нет значения причины, но предложение лучше изменить так:  **Ведь невозможно не ощутить всю гамму эмоций при виде того, как движущаяся бездна пожирает планеты.**

2) **Расчленение составных союзов**. [§ 34. Запятая при сложных подчинительных союзах](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=138#pp138)

"В зависимости от смысла и интонации, логического подчеркивания придаточной части сложноподчиненного предложения, наличия в предложении **определенных лексических элементов** и других условий сложный союз может расчленяться на две части: первая входит в состав главной части как соотносительное слово, а вторая выступает в роли союза".

В частности при противопоставлении (НЕ....А) союз расчленяется.

Answer (score 1):

А что ж вы маму-аса до конца-то не допытали?!

Во-первых, как вы и сказали, вопрос дискуссионный. Есть случаи (по счастью - немного), когда нет однозначного понимания, наречие это или предлог. Все советы будут субъективны.
Во-вторых, если вы хотите разобраться, а не формально зазубрить правило, то надо бы начать с более точного описания своих затруднений, а не нагромождать примеры... А вот "логики", вами обещанной, логической системы, я так и не обнаружил.

Но попробую.

(++++)

По первому вопросу. "Оттого" и "от того". Вы верно пишете, что первое - наречие (которое выступает обычно, если не всегда, в роли союзного слова), а второе - предлог в сочетании с указательным местоимением. 
Внутри предложения бывает, насколько я понимаю, только предлог. Тут вопросов нет, написание раздельное. Случаи неоконченных и грамматически неполных фраз (типа "Я люблю её не оттого, а по жизни"), где "что" подразумевается, выношу за скобки.

(++++)

Теперь второй вопрос, по поводу "от того, что" и "оттого(,) что". Тут сложнее и возможны случаи неоднозначные. Основное "правило": если "что" выступает в роли союзного слова (подлежащего в подчиненной части, реже - прямого дополнения), то это скорее всего случай предлога и местоимения "от того" и, таким образом, раздельного написания.

Иначе, если "что" обычный союз", скорее всего "оттого" - наречие.

Различить бывает непросто.

Иногда решает контекст.
*Я отталкивался от того, что движется*. - некий материальный объект способный двигаться и от которого можно оттолкнуться физически.

Я отталкивался оттого, что движется. - это про свойство объекта двигаться, того свойства можно оттолкнуться мысленно.

'*- От чего  вы решили, что это живое существо?*
'*- Я отталкивался оттого, что движется.*

Фраза искусственная, но смысл, надеюсь, понятен.
В этом значении "отталкиваться от" = "исходить из".

Когда-то давно, в старых традициях, случаи эти четко различали. Если речь шла о предмете, то написание "оттого, что" было почти невозможно. Если же раскрывалась причина, то, напротив, оно было единственно возможным. 
Сейчас же, в силу сближения понятий "от чего" и "почему" возможны варианты (см. у М_Г №11 - и мой комментарий к нему). Однако приоритетным всё же считаю именно такой поход, а не рассуждения о конкретном типе глагола и о том, к чему именно вопрос "почему?" относится. Если причина - "оттого что", Иначе

(++++)

И о запятой внутри **"оттого что"**. Неправильная у вас формулировка, я бы даже сказал "вредная". Речь-то идет о том, что "оттого что" (равно как и "потому что") в роли союза либо **разделятся запятой**, либо **отделяется предшествующей запятой** от остальной части. Но никак не о том, что запятую эту в каких-то случаях можно вообще опустить.

> ОТТОГО(,) ЧТО, союз
>
> Придаточные предложения, присоединяемые союзом «оттого(,) что»,
>   выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми. При этом союз может целиком
>   входить в придаточную часть (и не разделяться запятой), но может и
>   расчленяться (в этом случае запятая ставится между частями союза,
>   перед словом «что»). О факторах, влияющих на расстановку знаков
>   препинания, см. в Прил. 3.
>
> Художник, оттого что выпил два стакана портеру, как-то вдруг опьянел и
>   неестественно оживился. А. Чехов, Припадок. Мужики тихи, робки и
>   вежливы оттого, что у каждого для весу в кудели по камню, в муке много
>   песку, баран кожа да кости, курица чумная, только бы сдать, а не сдашь
>   и попадешься, тогда разговор краткий. М. Пришвин, Мирская чаша.
>   Оказалось, что учительница Инкамал-апай была у какой-то знаменитой
>   гадалки, которая, если добрая весть выйдет, ничего не берет, никакой
>   платы, оттого что сама радуется чужому счастью как своему. Ч.
>   Айтматов, Ранние журавли.

(Грамота.ру)
http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_518

Тут всё исчерпывающе.

Остальное смотрите в других ответах, там все верно по сути, не буду повторять.

Comment: О запятой теперь понятно, видимо, я не допоняла объяснения других, или они неточно написали, имею в виду, когда искала в сети ответ. Логика моего затруднения просто, тут я, похоже, неверно разъяснилась. Мои затруднения заключаются в том, что я засомневалась в правильности применения мною правила. Правильно ли я делаю выбор между "оттого" и "от того". И примеры привожу, конечно, которые и вызвали спорный вопрос. А про маму скажу, что сложно ее пытать, она правил не всех помнит досконально, но вот интуиция ее мало подводит. Вот я и запаниковала, как оказалось, не зря!